# How do I figure this one out? $p\in (0,1) \sum_{k\in Uneven}(1-p)^{k-1}p$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

How do I figure this one out? $$p\in (0,1) \sum_{k\in Uneven}(1-p)^{k-1}p; Uneven=\{1,3,5,7...\}$$

I know that if $k\in \mathbb N$ then this sum would be equal to one, because this is like the geometric distribution. But what about only over uneven numbers? Just $\frac{1}{2}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about why it is equal to 1 for $k \in \mathbb N$ and extend it. Let $p \in (0,1)$. You want to find

$$\sum_{k\in \{1,3,5,...\}}^\infty(1-p)^{k-1}p$$ which is equivalent to just summing $p(1-p)^k$ for $k \in \{0,2,4,6,...\}$ which is equivalent to:

$$p\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-p)^{2k}$$

This sum is equal to the infinite sum of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) with $r = (1-p)^2$ and so you have

$$ 
\begin{split}
\text{Sum} &= p\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-p)^{2k} \\
& = p\frac{1}{1-(1-p)^2} \\
&= \frac{p}{2p-p^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2-p} 
\end{split}
$$

Comment: If the exponent is an odd minus one...

Comment: @robjohn Sorry, was mid editing :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It might be better to write the sum simply as
$$
p\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-p)^{2k}
$$
then use the [formula for the sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Answer (score 0):

try to rewrite your sum: use $k=2n+1$ for any $n \in \aleph_0$  instead of $k$ uneven; therefore you have

$$ \sum_{n \in \aleph_0} (1-p)^{(2n+1)-1}p = p  \sum_{n \in \aleph_0} ((1-p)^{2})^{n}  $$
 and can use geometric series because $(1-p)^{2} < 1 $ because $ (1-p)<0 $ and it follows

$$ = p  \frac{1}{1-((1-p)^{2})} = \frac{p}{2p-p^2} = \frac{1}{2-p} $$

Hope, it helps^^